# Styled-components with animate.css

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, animate.css, styled-components

I use [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) in my project. Now I would like to implement some simple animations like [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Is that possible to use [react-animations](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-animations) (or similar library) with [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) ?

It's a waste of time to implements animations like in [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) again. Additionally I don't want to install anothers package as *Aphrodite* because I have *styled-components* already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an [answer](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/823) with [code](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KktjocigcjvHnP_lPJp):

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import { fadeIn } from 'react-animations';

const fader = keyframes`${fadeIn}`;

// Create a <Title> react component that renders an <h1> which is
// centered, palevioletred and sized at 1.5em
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
  animation: 1s ${fader} alternate infinite;
`;

// Create a <Wrapper> react component that renders a <section> with
// some padding and a papayawhip background
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: papayawhip;
`;


export default () => {
  // Render these styled components like normal react components. They will pass on all props and work
  // like normal react components – except they're styled!
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title>Hello World, this is my first styled component!</Title>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is correct way to perform animations with styled-components but please keep in mind that each such dynamic change will generate new <style> tag with new classes.
So for highly dynamic animations it can cause performance issues.

Please see this thread for more information https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/134